# Callback function for all of the rendering in server

Tags: node.js, express

When using express in Node.js, is there a way to perform a function EACH TIME a page is being rendered (or, after each time the 'res.render' function is called)?

I want to have some kind of middleware that will track which pages renders at the user requests, and send this information to analytics, but this middleware should only be performed when rendering HTML pages, and not when responding with regular statuses or JSON.

Comment: > *"but this middleware should only be performed when rendering HTML pages, and not when responding with regular statuses or JSON."* Can you elaborate how in your code you're making this distinction?  All middle-ware functions run every time a user makes a requests (if they're reachable). You should be able to place/call this middle-ware using the same distinction so that it too is only called when that condition is met/not met.